# package javafx.embed.swing is not visible maven JDK 17

Tags: java, maven, swing, javafx

I am new to Maven. I need to include

```
private javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel jFXPanel1;
```

To a new project with uses Maven + Jigsaw modules.

I have the following problem with `javafx.embed.swing` package.

[image: Problem]

I thought that adding this dependency would work, but it does not.

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-swing -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
    <version>19</version>
</dependency>
```

On clean install, I see the following

> (package javafx.embed.swing is declared in the unnamed module, but module com.my.module does not read it)

[image]

I don't understand this. I see that JAR, it only has a manifest file, and no `.class` files, which confuses me even more.

If I look in the m2 folder, I see a different JAR with the same prefix, but with `win` suffix and there I see the package.

I think this is the classifier

```xml
<classifier>${javafx.platform}</classifier>
```

And I think, but I don't know, if this jar is being picked by Maven or not, but it seems it is not, because I don't see it in the IntelliK libraries.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I don't have any problem with JavaFX, everything is modular out there and is working. I have the problem only with this jar.

***-----------------------------UPDATE-----------------------------------***

The culprit here was IntellijIdea i did click on **File->Invalidate caches** later restart it. Later i could see the dependency loaded.

[image: Dependency loaded.]

Later i could add the module
[image: Added module]

[image: dependency loaded.]

And i can see now the dependency and that's it. Thanks.

Comment: The module is called `javafx.swing`, not `javafx.embed.swing`.

Comment: Don’t use `ea` version software.  Use a recent stable release, not an obsolete early access release.  For JavaFX, that is currently `19.0.2`.  And don’t mix versions of JavaFX software, use the exact same version for all JavaFX dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

Just declaring a Maven dependency is simply not enough. You also have to make the Java module system happy. You have to declare this additional dependency in your module-info.java file of your project too. Javas module system knows nothing about Maven dependencies.

Comment: but how i do that? i put requires the package and says it does exist.

Comment: i dont have problems with JavaFX just with that particular class

Comment: You may have messed up your setup already. E.g., remove the explicit classifier handling. It is not needed.

Comment: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/